# What is the name of this kind of selection in flutter/Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to create this kind of horizontal selection in Dart/flutter. Can anyone help me on how to do it or any documentation.

Here is a image sample of what am looking for:
[image: image sample]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by using Carousel Slider with text as slider element.

See this.. [carousel_slider_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider)

Comment: Thanks for reply, but those data needed to be submitted to the database. Its like a select options in which what selected can be submitted

Comment: onPageChanged will give you the current index. from where you can get the data what user selected before start playing.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Row with a PageView widget sandwiched between 2 buttons.
Use a PageController to change the selections when the buttons are clicked.